# join all columns in table1 to columns with "unique names" in table2

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using mySQL 5.6.  I have two tables: t1 and t2.  Both have many columns.  And many columns in t1 and t2 share the same name: for example, there is a "var1" column in t1 and in t2.

I want to join the tables, selecting (a) all columns from t1 and (b) only the columns in t2 that have names that don't appear in t1.  For example, I would not select "var1" from t2.

Here is a valid mySQL command that does not work because some columns share the same name:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.ID=t2.ID);
```

MySQL sensibly returns this error message:

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'var1'
```

So I want to run a command like

```
SELECT t1.*, DISTINCTCOLUMNS(t2.*) FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.ID=t2.ID);
```

Except, of course, that there is no DISTINCTCOLUMNS operation in SQL.  But is there a similar (real) command that will achieve the same effect?

I see that common advice is to avoid `SELECT *` syntax, partly for efficiency purposes.  I appreciate that, but I do not want to write out the names of all of the columns that I need.

Comment: Write out the names of the columns.  It is not that hard.  You can use `information_schema.columns` to get the list of columns.

Comment: @JohnRuddell -- thank you for your answer.  With regret, it doesn't solve my issue.  I acknowledge the virtue of spelling out the names of particular columns, and that is what I almost always do -- but in some special cases, including this one, I really do want to tackle the problem without spelling out particular column names.

Comment: @user697473 you cannot pull out two columns with the same name in one select it just doesn't work. you will have to at least eliminate the duplicate column names. can you post a sqlfiddle with the table columns to test with?

Comment: "you cannot pull out two columns with the same name in one select" -- yes, that's the problem.  I've been thinking of alternatives that involve using information_schema to systematically rename the columns in `t2`, e.g., by adding a prefix to the name of each column in that table.  I'll try to soon post an sqlfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue here is you have the same column name for both tables. So you need to alias your columns.. This is also why you shouldn't just pull all columns out but the specific ones you need..

```
SELECT t1.ID as t1_id,
       t1.var1 as t1_var1,
       t2.ID as t2_id,
       t2.var1 as t2_var1,
       ... Etc.
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

With two ID columns and no way to distinguish between the two an error will occur

Answer (score 0):

You could qualify the columns like

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.ID=t2.ID);
```

But you should not do it unless the columns with identical names do actually hold/reference the same data.

Comment: Thank you -- but with such a command, I get a "Duplicate column name" error message.

Comment: Sorry - it worked, when I tested: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f507f/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

try like following. this may help you

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.YourDesiredColumnName FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.ID=t2.ID);
```